# Creating a chat view with a scroll pane and dynamical loading

Tags: java, javafx, xmpp

I am currently working on a xmpp chat application with JavaFX and want to create a chat view which is inspired by Telegram.

My current problem is the message loading system. In particular the preloading. I want to preload messages when the user is scrolling up. The problem is when i adding the message views to my VBox which is wrapped in a ScrollPane the ScrollPane scrolls to the top. But i want that the viewport stays where it is while adding stuff at the top. I really don't know how to solve that as smooth as in Telegram. I already wrote something that sets the vvalue of the ScrollPane to the offset which is added but the function bugs sometimes and isn't really smooth.

Here is the trigger which loading the messages and the height listener which resets the vvalue of the ScrollPane:

```
    // Chat View scrolling listener
    ChangeListener<Object> changeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(chatScrollBox.getVvalue() <= 0.01) {
            updateMessages(userHandler.getUserList(), true);
        }
    };
    chatScrollBox.vvalueProperty().addListener(changeListener);

    // Reset the vvalue when something added
    chatBox.heightProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        double offset = newValue.doubleValue() - oldValue.doubleValue();
        chatScrollBox.setVvalue((scrollDown ? 1.0d : getVvalueFromOffset(offset)));

        if(currentChat != null) {
            int cacheSize = (chatStorage.get(currentChat) == null ? 0 : chatStorage.get(currentChat).size()-1);
            if(cacheSize <= 10) {
                chatBox.layout();
                chatScrollBox.setVvalue(1.0d);
            }
        }
    });
```